# Spring Boot using RestController and ServletRegistrationBean in same application

Tags: servlets, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, alexa-skills-kit

I have a Controller class annotated with `@RestController` containing `@ReguestMapping` annotations on the class' methods to identify the endpoints.

I need to add a `SpeechletServlet` (part of the Alexa-skill-kit) to receive requests at an endpoint `/zebra-tape` at the same time that the other endpoints are still available.

Using the code below I loose access to the endpoints annotated with `@RequestMapping`

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ZebraTapeServlet());
        registration.addUrlMappings("/zebra-tape");
        return registration;
    }
}
```

How can I have access to both types of endpoints?

Comment: The Spring docs suggest the correct answer given below. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your bean method to something other than `dispatcherServletRegistration`. That name is used by Spring Boot for the registration bean for the auto-configured dispatcher servlet. By declaring a bean method with the same name, you are switching that auto-configuration off.